# Error when creating an index using mappings file

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch 1.5.2 on CentOS as a service.
I tried to add mappings using PUT:

```
curl -XPUT $ES_HOST/my_index -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

That request works fine and creates new index with correct mappings. 
Instead of putting mappings manually I want to store mappings on server in config files. For that I created file `/etc/elasticsearch/mappings/my_index/all_mappings.json` with the same content as previous request body. After that I'm trying to create index `curl -XPUT $ES_HOST/my_index` but the error occurs

```
{
    "error": "MapperParsingException[mapping [all_mappings]]; nested: 
                MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! 
                Remaining fields:   [mappings : {my_type={properties={field={type=nested}}}}]]; ",
    "status": 400
}
```

I tried to remove `mappings` field in config json but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file is the mapping name. So, for `/mappings/my_index/all_mappings.json` you should have the index `my_index` and the `type` called `all_mappings`.

Also, the content of the file should be:

```
   {
     "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
```

These being said, do the following:

- create a `my_type.json` file under `/etc/elasticsearch/mappings/my_index` folder
- put inside that file the following:

```
   {
     "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
```

- call `PUT /test_my_index`
- check the mapping: `GET /test_my_index/_mapping`

Comment: Thanks, it is works! Elastic documentation contains little information about these aspects https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-conf-mappings.html